# Using a lambda inside Linq.Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, methodinfo

I need to call a lambda from a Linq.Expression. I know I can get some method info from the lambda like this:

```
Func<double, double> square = x => x * x;
MethodInfo mInfo = square.Method;
```

But that MethodInfo requires a `System.RuntimeServices.Closure` first argument. Since I'm using .NET Core, that class is internal to `System.Linq.Expressions`. Even when an instance of that class is created using reflection, I cannot call square from a System.Linq.Expression.

Is there any workaround for this? I'm writing a simple formula evaluator, but I need lambdas for implementing thinks like predicate logic, Newton-Raphson, etc.

Updated:

This code does not work:

```
        static void Main(string[] args) =>
            Console.WriteLine(DoubleIt()(4));

        static double CallAndDouble(Func<double, double> f, double x)
        {
            return f(x) + f(x);
        }

        static Func<double, double> DoubleIt()
        {
            var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "x");
            var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(CallAndDouble)),
                CreateLambda(), input);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double>>(call, input).Compile();
        }

        static Expression CreateLambda()
        {
            var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "x");
            var mult = Expression.Multiply(input, input);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double>>(mult, input);
        }
```

In actual code, I'll have some library functions taking lambdas as arguments (like the `CallAndDouble` from the above code).

Comment: Changed `var` to `Func<double, double>`.

Comment: The only thing you can do is to construct an expression which invokes that `square` lambda (i.e. `Expression<Func<double, double>> expr = x => square(x)`). There's no way to construct an expression which represents the operation `x * x`

Comment: Even with the change, it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to achieve. Please provide more context - including how you expect to use the expression tree later.

Comment: More code added.

Comment: Your code works for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oEGtpG . It's doing `(4 * 4) + (4 * 4)` because that's what you constructed, but hey. What exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: Ha, ha, canton7! It doesn't work for me! Yes, that's what it is supossed to do. Might it be that I'm running it in .NET Core 5? It throws an `ArgumentNullException` at the second line in `DoubleIt`. I'll try it in FW 4.8 to check that.

Comment: @IanMarteens I had to fix the BindingFlags passed to `GetMethod`, because it's not set up to find a private method by default.... But I assumed that was an error with your sample which wasn't there in your actual code, because it's nothing at all to do with expressions or lambdas, just `GetMethod` returning null

Comment: Geez, I'm an idiot. Thanks, @canton7

Comment: No problem! Voting to close this as "Caused by a typo" -- while it wasn't exactly a typo, it's still something unrelated to the original question which is unlikely to help others

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @canton7. Just a typo: I was missing the BindingFlags.